# How can I tell pytest-dependency to temporarily ignore test dependencies?

Tags: python, pytest, functional-testing, pytest-dependency

I've got a functional test suite using pytest-dependency to skip tests when other tests they depend on fail. That way, for example, if the login page is broken, I get one test failure saying "The login page is broken" instead of a slew of test failures saying "I couldn't log into user X", "I couldn't log into user Y", etc.

This works great for running the entire suite, but I'm trying to shorten my edit-compile-test loop, and right now the slowest point is testing my tests. If the test I'm working on has a bunch of other tests it depends on, they all have to succeed in order to not skip the test I'm trying to test. So, I either have to run the entire dependency tree, or comment out my `@pytest.mark.dependency(...)` decorators (which is an additional thing that I, as a human, have to remember to do). Technically there's nothing these depended-on tests do that enables their dependers to run - the only reason I want these dependencies at all is to make it easier for me to triage test failures.

Is there a command-line argument that would tell pytest-dependency to not skip things on account of dependents, or to tell pytest to not use the pytest-dependency plugin on this run (and this run only)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-p` option allows disabling a particular plugin:

```
pytest -p no:dependency
```

Comment: This works, but IMO is just *ok*.  When using `-p no:dependency`, I get a ton of warnings about unknown dependencies, which is overwhelming.  Now I want to filter out those warnings when `-p no:dependency` is used.